# iOS 13 couldn't receive BLE data on background mode

Tags: ios, xcode, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have an app developing on iOS 12 connecting a device with BLE. After zoom out this app into iPhoneX's desktop we could still receive data from device. But developing this app on iOS 13, we find that app stopping receive data after 1 minutes. List after images is Xcode setting :

[Xcode background modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJwiz.png)

[Xcode info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Hez.png)
Does there anyone have the solution for this ? Thanks in advance.